# Numbering rows of a text block inside a table

Tags: tables

As in the title I need to number the rows of a block of text inside a table, the numbers should take the space needed for two digits while the table should fill all the remaning space like in the figure below.

The red boxes represent the margins of my page (A4, 2.5cm top/bottom, 1.9cm right/left, header and footer), the black box inside represent the actual border of the table surrounding the loret ipsum text.

I've tried using the tabularx package witouth success, how can I achieve this result?

[image]

As requested this is a minimal version of my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1.9cm, right=1.9cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
% here should go the table and the row numbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add your code starting from  `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.  I do not to understand why you need a table to number lines of text.

Comment: @Simon Dispa I do not need a table to number lines of text, I need to number the line of text inside a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\internallinenumbers`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r|>{\internallinenumbers}X|}
\cline{2-2}
&\lipsum[2]\par\\
\cline{2-2}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I need the text to be inside a table, also the line numbering are outside the margin shown in the figure

Comment: `\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | r>{\internallinenumbers}X |}\hline
&\lipsum[2]\par \\ hline` is very close to the expected result! Is it possible to exclude the line numbering from the border of the table?

Comment: @Fabio Yes, use `{r|>{\internallinenumbers}X|}` and `\cline{2-2}` instead of `\hline`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

This code will number the lines in a `longtable` row, but of course it won't make an auto pagebreak if the content of the row is too long.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, left=1.9cm, right=1.9cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{lineno}% line numbers
\def\linenumberfont{\normalfont\small\sffamily}
\linenumbersep=15pt

\usepackage{array} % p column
\usepackage{kantlipsum}% dumy text

\usepackage{showframe} % show the margins <<<<<<<<
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\Large
        
    \begin{longtable}{p{1.5ex}| >{\internallinenumbers}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-4\tabcolsep-1.5ex}|} 
        \hline
    &   \kant[1-2]\\\hline
    &   \kant[3-4]
    \end{longtable} 
        
\end{document}
```